# One or more UINavigation Controllers when displaying a new View Controller for each option in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

To show a new view controller for each option in a UITableView controller, can this be done with only one UINavigation controller, or do you need to have one for each menu option and the subsequent View Controller that a option will display?

Comment: add code here .

Comment: Add the Table view controller itself in the navigation controller and on cell selection just push the relevant view controller.

Comment: Most probably this can is achievable using only one Navigation Controller. Your root view controller should be Navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use 1 Navigation Controller and just push the other View Controllers. Ctrl + drag from UINavigation Controller to the TableView Controller that has got the menu. Then Drag from the menu items to each new View Controller and select 'Show'.

NOTE: This does not work when you have a View Controller with a TableView Controller embedded in it by means of a Container View.